# Как выбрать префикс в class или префикс для id в js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.manager*').click(function ()  {
        var managerid = $('.manager*').data('manager');
        $('#manager_id').val(managerid);
    });
```

Побывал так

```
var managerid = $("div:regex(class, .*manager.*)")
```

Comment: Напишите ваш код html и подробнее распишите что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваш пример не работает, т.к. регулярные выражение (в качестве селектора) в jqurery не поддерживаются в стандартной сборке (по крайней мере 1 и 2 версии), может быть поэтому Ваш код не работает. Вам нужно [плагин подключить](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)
2. Либо достаточно использовать: [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

   Будет выглядеть так: `$('div[id^="manager"]')`

   Пример можно [глянуть здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/e9wz8qs3/4/)